# singular matrix and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw the following statement but do not know how to show:

Let $L:R^n \to R^n$ be a linear transformation specified by a matrix $M$. If $M$ is singular, then $L$ maps the $n$-dimensional set $E$ into $R^m$, where $m<n$.

Can someone tell me why this is true? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the rank-nullity theorem:
$$n=\dim\ker(L)+\dim\mathrm{im}(L)=\dim\ker(L)+m.$$